# Compute addition and subtraction of an arithmetic expression without 'is'

Tags: prolog

How can I find the result of an arithmetic expression composed of pluses and minuses without using 'is'?

For example, to find the result of 1+2+3+4-6, I do: `X is 1+2+3+4-6` and I get: `X = 4`.

What I've tried so far:

```
    eval(EXPR, EXPR) :- 
        integer(EXPR), 
        !.
    eval(X+Y, RES) :- 
        eval(X, X1), 
        eval(Y, Y1), 
        plus(X1, Y1, RES).
    eval(X-Y, RES) :- 
        eval(X, X1), 
        eval(Y, Y1), 
        Y2 = -Y1, 
        plus(X1, Y2, RES).
```

but when I try to compute an expression containing negative numbers, I get the error: `` `integer' expected, found `- number`  (a compound) ``.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `plus(Y1,Y2,0)` instead of `Y2 = -Y1`.

In the latter case, Y2 is a structure with functor - and Argument Y1, whereas in the former case, Y1 is a number.

Take `Y1 = 3` for example. [Just for fun: try it with `Y1 = -3`]

```
?- Y1 = 3, Y2 = -Y1, Y2 =.. L.
Y1 = 3,
Y2 = - 3,
L = [-, 3].

?- Y1 = 3, plus(Y1,Y2,0), Y2 =.. L.
Y1 = 3,
Y2 = -3,
L = [-3].
```

However, `Y2` is supposed to be an argument in the predicate `plus/3`, which does not allow structures as arguments.

Maybe you prefer this solution:

```
eval(X-Y, RES) :- 
    eval(X, X1), 
    eval(Y, Y1), 
    plus(Y1, RES, X1).
```

Comment: It works. Thanks, but what is the thinking behind it?

Comment: with Y2=-Y1, Y2 is a structure with the functor '-' and the argument 'Y1'. A structure is not a number. plus/3 is an inbuilt predicate that operates on numbers. So in this case, Y2 is a number.

Comment: Is this the only way to get the negative value?

Comment: you could also use Y2 is -Y1, of course ;-), but that is surely NOT what you want.

Comment: Any idea if the exercise can be solved in any other way?

Comment: There are many. I've added one in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229686/discussion-between-tiffi-and-ghost).